# Matrix terminology

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, linear-algebra

I've found three useful operations when dealing with lists of lists.

```
mat=[list('abc'),list('pqr'),list('xyz')]
```

1.`mat=[x for sl in mat for x in sl]` ("flatten")

2. `mat=list(zip(*mat))` (transposing)
3. `mat=mat[::-1]` ("flip"; first becomes latter and vice versa)

What is the *specific terminology* for these operations, and which key operations am I overlooking?

Comment: I guess you can call them list transformations. Another useful transformation is rotation: moving items from one end of the list and adding them to the other; the usual way to do that in Python is via slicing.

Comment: BTW, you can do your initial construction using `map`,  although it doesn't make much difference with only 3 strings. `mat = list(map(list, ('abc', 'pqr', 'xyz')))`. Also, `list(zip(*[iter('abdpqrxyz')]*3))`, or `list(map(list,zip(*[iter('abdpqrxyz')]*3)))` if the inner sequences must be lists rather than tuples.

Answer (score 0):

1. In my corner of the world, this is often called “rasterizing” a matrix (though we might be appropriating the term from image processing). Numpy calls it [`ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html). Matlab calls it “vectorize” and uses the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) (search for `A(:)`).
2. Transpose is the standard mathematical and numerical name.
3. Numpy and Matlab both call this `fliplr` (left–right) and `flipud` (up–down).

There are a ton of other matrix operations, some more common, some less. A look thru Numpy/Matlab/Julia/etc. documentation will blow your mind.